# Graph APi - Get user Mailboxes in the order as in Outlook

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I am working with the Microsoft Graph API to get Mailboxes from an authenticated user and I want the mailboxes in the order as how it is also displayed in Outlook itself.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?includeHiddenFolders=true&$expand=childFolders&$top=500

in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Gives me the full list with the childrenfolders but in the order of Alphabeth on the main folders.

`$orderby` does not help as it only is able to order by displayName which is not what I want.

My solution right now, store the mailbox id's in a local db table with the order I want but it feels soo counterintuitive

I am using PHP but for the graph API I am only interested in the right URL endpoint to query which is not language dependable.

Any ideas or suggestions...ChatGPT was not helpful :)

I used https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer the graph explorer to find the right endpoint to retrieve the result in the desired order but I could not

Answer (score 0):

When you change order, Outlook sets [PR_SORT_POSITION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/stephen_griffin/mapi-provider-sorting) binary property (`0x3020`, `PT_BINARY`) on the folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68228599/332059. Specify that property when doing the `mailFolders` call: `singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Binary 0x3020')`:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?includeHiddenFolders=true&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties%28%24filter%3Did%20eq%20%27Binary%200x3020%27%29

Comment: Is it applicable to stores in Outlook, not only regular folders?

Comment: No, the store order cannot possibly come from Graph - it is local to a particular Outlook installation: imagine you have local PST stores in the profile. The order in which Outlook shows local stores comes from the (`0x0458, PT_MV_BINARY`) property in the  `IID_CAPONE_PROF` (`{00020D0A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`) profile section.

Comment: The question was for the order of stores, not folders.

Comment: The OP is using `mailFolders` in Graph, which returns top level **folders** in a given mailbox in the alphabetical order rather that the order displayed by Outlook, which is what the OP is apparently having a problem with.

Comment: Looking at the title I don't think so.