# Adding a new folder to an Outlook folder is added as the second folder

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-automation

I want to add a folder to an existing folder in Outlook.

```
OApp = new();
Ons = OApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
OMapiFld = Ons.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
OFriendsFld = OMapiFld.Folders["Friends"];
OFFolder = (Folder)OFriendsFld.Folders.Add("Jack", OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

If the Friends folder has other items already like

Friends - (1) Jan (2) Andrew

When I add a new Jack folder it appears like this

Friends (1) Jan (2) Jack (3) Andrew

The question I have is why is it always added as the second item in the sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook email folders are sorted alphabetically by default. In Outlook, click `Folder` and see if `Show All Folders A to Z` button is highlighted; if it is, all folders are sorted alphabetically. At this time, when you right-click any folder, the `Sort subfolder A to Z` option is not available.

[image: Outlook folder sorting order]

You may sort Outlook folders alphabetically by right-clicking the account or inbox folder and then select the sort subfolders A to Z options.

You can sort the folders in the Outlook UI programmatically by explicitly setting the `PR_SORT_POSITION` property on each subfolder. Read more about that in the [Outlook VBA to Replicate 'Sort Subfolders A to Z' in the Folder Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68227452/outlook-vba-to-replicate-sort-subfolders-a-to-z-in-the-folder-pane) thread.

Comment: My Outlook client does not have Show All Folders A to Z highlighted.

Comment: You can customize ribbon controls that are displayed on the ribbon.